How to allow incoming connections only from the left side of a shape in draw.io /app.diagrams.net?
I use a vertical line as a shape for a mxCell (represening a bus) in xml code for draw.io /app.diagrams.net:
    <object label="pre_production" id="pre_production">
      <mxCell style="shape=line;direction=north;strokeColor=black;strokeWidth=4;verticalLabelPosition=top;verticalAlign=bottom;" parent="1" vertex="1">
        <mxGeometry x="239.03053544207313" y="136.11933043336302" width="2" height="80" as="geometry" />
      </mxCell>
    </object>


For its parent cell I specified a horizontal flow layout:
<mxCell id="1" style="childLayout=flowLayout;flowOrientation=west;" parent="0" />

How can I specify that incoming connections are only allowed to the left of the (line) shape? And outgoing connections should only be allowed from the right side.
In the layout I want the incoming connections to bend around the bus and enter it from the left side, instead of entering it from the right side.
a) Maybe I could define some custom connection points or perimeter. If I do so, how to differentiate between incoming and outgoing connections?
b) If it is not possible to specify that behavior for the node element, how to specify it for the layout?
Related:

https://www.drawio.com/doc/faq/shape-connection-points-customise
https://www.drawio.com/doc/faq/shape-perimeter-change
https://www.drawio.com/doc/faq/connectors
https://www.drawio.com/doc/faq/apply-layouts
https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/docs/js-api/files/layout/hierarchical/mxHierarchicalLayout-js.html

